# get file input in ie 7 ,8 , 9 with jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want get file from input file and send file to server but I can not do in ie 7,8,9 
how I can get file from input tag in ie 7,8,9

html

```
<input name="file" id="file" type="file" />
```

script

```
var control = document.getElementById('file');
    var file = control.files[0];
    var name = file.name;
    var size = file.size;
```

Comment: I don't think you can get the file contents...

Comment: You can't in IE 7,8,9 as noted elsewhere, what are you trying to do? Just upload the file asynchronously, or are you wanting to do more?

Comment: Well I wouldn’t say it’s impossible in general – but instead of JavaScript one might have to use techniques like Active-X, VBScript or other atrocities … so most likely not worth the hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in ie 7,8,9 so you need a button to submit the form normally.

Answer (score 0):

[IE does not support the File API before version 10](http://caniuse.com/#search=fileapi).

If you want to support those browsers, you'll need to take a different approach, such as using Flash.